# Why is FindOne where id using typeorm and mongodb doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, typeorm

I am using typeorm with MongoDB. When I am searching for a document by Id with this syntax
`const manager = getMongoManager(); const user = await manager.findOne(User, {userId});` I got undefined result and when I use `const manager = getMongoManager(); const user = await manager.findOne(User, {});` I got the result with userId expected in the first syntax.

Besides the same syntax works fine with any other criteria other than Id.

The declaration of the Id in the model is: `@ObjectIdColumn({ name: '_id' }) @IsNotEmpty() public userId: ObjectID;`

For now, I have only one user in the database with the userId that I search for.

Where could be the problem? And how to resolve that?

Answer (score 4):

You should query using `_id` instead of id. You also need to convert the id from string to MongoDB's `ObjectId` object before making the query.

```
require mongodb from 'mongodb';

await manager.findOne(User, { _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(<your _id>)});
```

Comment: That did the trick! thanks!
I was facing this error when using typeorm with mongodb.
To do this, fixed my issue:
`const mongoId = new ObjectId(userId)`
And then I query my repository with the mongoId

Answer (score 1):

When you do `await manager.findOne(User, {});` You are basically selecting the first entry in your User collection, that's why you get the user you were expecting.

What you need to do is query by the `_id` field if you have it, or create a custom field to query by, for example:

```
@Entity()
export class UserEntity
{
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  _id: string;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  public name: string;
}
```

This way you can do a query like this `await manager.findOne(User, { _id: <your _id>});`

Or `await manager.findOne(User, { id: <your id> });`

Comment: But, what is the problem if I user userId instead of _id? They point on the same thing, no?

Comment: Creating two columns with the same property doesn't seem to be a good thing to do.